# What are the tabs of this song

Tags: guitar

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

There is a guitar part which I have been trying to come up with the tabs and the tuning it is (doesn't sound like standard tuning)

I not great at breaking video apart and figuring tabs out.

I was hoping someone could help me with that or just give me some advice

This is the [Song](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bvw6dPjFtLZ/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because transcription requests are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

A quick whip up. It's in standard tuning (E2 A2 D3 G3 B3 E4). I don't claim it to be exactly as played but maybe it's good enough to get you started. The chords are just simple notes and to have something to aim at, and without the flageoletts/harmonics.

Cheers,

[image: Simple chords, notes and tab]